# Filter search results in React

Tags: reactjs, search, filter

So I make an axios request to a backend service. I got the data back, rendered it on the page and filtered it by text search but now, what I want to do now is to hide the search results and only render the search results when a user types in the input field. I dont know how to go about it.
This is my code so far

```
const HealthFacilities = () => {
  const [entityType] = useState('HealthFacility')
  const [ehxFacilities, setEhxFacilities] = useState([])
  const [keyStroke, setKeyStroke] = useState()
  const [filteredEhxFacilities, setFilteredEhxFacilities] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const [dataPerPage] = useState(globalConfig.paginationLimit)

  const onFetchHandler = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    await axios
      .get(
        `${globalConfig.apiServicesUrl}ehx-healthcare-facilities/?filter[limit]=100`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${globalConfig.bearerTokenValue}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        setFilteredEhxFacilities(Array.from(response.data))
        setEhxFacilities(Array.from(response.data))
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredFacility = ehxFacilities.filter(ehxFacility => {
      return (
        ehxFacility.healthcareFacilityName
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        ehxFacility.city?.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        ehxFacility.description?.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
        ehxFacility.address1?.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    })

    setFilteredEhxFacilities(filteredFacility)
  }, [search])

  useEffect(() => {
    onFetchHandler()
  }, [])

  const indexOfLastData = currentPage * dataPerPage
  const indexOfFirstData = indexOfLastData - dataPerPage
  const currentData = filteredEhxFacilities.slice(
    indexOfFirstData,
    indexOfLastData
  )

  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber)

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setSearch(e.target.value)
    console.log(e.target.value.length)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container lg={'fluid'}>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={8} md={10}>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  name="search"
                  value={search}
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                  placeholder="Search Facilities"
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={4} md={2}>
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: '/manage-healthcare-facility',
                search: `?id=0&entityType=${entityType}`,
              }}
            >
              <Button variant="success" size="md">
                <FaPlus /> New
              </Button>
            </Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Table responsive="sm" striped hover bordered>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Facility Name</th>
              <th scope="col">City</th>
              <th scope="col">Address</th>
              <th scope="col">Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <FindEhxHealthCareFacility
              facilities={currentData}
              loading={loading}
              colNums={4}
            />
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}

export default HealthFacilities
```

Comment: Based on the `search` character length, you can hide the search results panel.

Comment: That worked @UKS. Thank you